# Expresso Store v2.1.0 can an individual product modifier be tax free?

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers, tax

I'm trying to find a way of allowing a client to mark specific product modifiers as tax free, can it be done somehow?

For example, a shoe at certain sizes (for children) will be tax free but other sizes will remain taxable at the normal rate.

I should also point out that they don't want to create another category for the tax free products. They would rather have a checkbox to say this size is tax free (or similar).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Store outside of categories but even with that you can't have a modifier that is a different category then the rest of the entry.

You will need to write an extension that creates a new variation type that they could select from the drop down on the publish page. In your variation you will still was a name and price field but you would then add a tax free checkbox. From there you would have to add the logic to prevent taxi from being applied based upon your new variation column when items are add/edit in the cart. You should take a look at the available [extension hooks](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html).

Comment: Thanks for confimation Justin, I thought that might be the case on this occasion. So I'll have to see if the client wants to proceed with a custom extension.